# No explanation "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to to implement autocomplete.

I have an issue like

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

This is my code.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.search').keyup(function(e){
        var input = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "class/contact/get_contact_list.php",
            data: {"current_user_id" : window.USER_DATA.USER.id_user, "type" : "verify", "search": input},
            async: true,
            success: function(data){
                var outWords = $.parseJSON(data);
                $('.data_contact').html('');
                $('.data_contact').prepend($(Chat.append_into_contact_list(outWords,'search')));
                // $('.data_contact').prepend('<div>'+input+'_'+outWords.response.length+'</div>'); //Fills the #auto div with the options
                //$('.data_contact').append($(Chat.append_into_contact_list(outWords,'search')).delay(220).fadeTo('slow',1));
                console.log(outWords);
            }

        })
    })
});
</script>
```

I think it was an error that lies in `$('.data_contact').prepend($(Chat.append_into_contact_list(outWords,'search')));`.

Can anyone please suggest what's causing the issue?

Comment: What is the *actual* value of `data`? Chances are it is not as expected. *Don't* use alert; use the console/debugger, and possibly the network monitor.

Comment: What do you see when you say alert(data) instead of alert(outwords.length)?

Comment: sorry, i copy old code.

i implement like this

 $('.data_contact').prepend('<div>'+input+'_'+outWords.length+'</div>'); 

and outWords is no amount.

Comment: That simply means that the object `outWords` doesn't have a `length` property. What is wrong is that you are trying to access a property that does not exist. Don't do that. You can only access properties that exist.

Comment: Oh, I see.
Thank you answer.
I will learn even more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parseJSON parses a string (which has length) to an Object - which does not necessarily have a length

Comment: But the error is that outWords evaluates to undefined.. there is no problem reading a non-existent property; but it is not possible read properties of the `undefined` value.

Comment: ya, the outWords.length is undefined

Comment: @user2864740 - no, outWords.length was undefined